# Display time in AM/PM format

Tags: java, time

I've written this code that display the current time, but my problem is it doesn't diplay time with am or pm format, it just displays, for example, 12:00. without am or pm

```
    java.util.Calendar thetime = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
    int h = thetime.get(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int m = thetime.get(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE);

    System.out.println("the current time is"+ h +":"+m);
```

Comment: did u read the Calendar api before posting this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding:

```
int a_p = thetime.get(java.util.Calendar.AM_PM);
String am_pm;
if(a_p==0)
    am_pm = "AM";
else
    am_pm = "PM";
```

Then add `am_pm` at the end of your output.

Anyway you should prefer SimpleDateFormat, try looking at it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 4):

You should rather use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
String time = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a").format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it manually, e.g.

```
String ampm = h > 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
// now print the variable ampm
```

Or even better use SimpleDateFormat. Please refer this class' javadoc to learn how to configure it. It will take 5 minutes first time but then save your time.

Answer (score 1):

As your servlet prints out the only the values you should better use DateFormat to set how to print the values.

As an example:

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, <put your locale here>);
```

See [DateFormat class here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

use **calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM)**

it will return integer value 1 if current time is in PM or else 0 which indicates AM.
go through this [link](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/CurrentTime.shtml)..

Answer (score 0):

Use DateFormatter to display the time in a String format.[Here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/parsedate.html)